# how to know if developer did a rebase in a topic branch in Git

Tags: git

I would like to ensure people use rebase before merging a topic branch.
so I am looking a way to know if a person has done it. is there a way with

```
git log
```

?

Comment: Why does it matter if a rebase was performed? Diffing exists for a reason.

Comment: to ensure a practice. कर्म

Comment: Yes, I'm asking _why_ that is your practice, though. Rebasing shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: project with tons of people, mutiple topic branches , when we merge , we mess the log , I think rebasing we can keep a cleaner log of commits.

Comment: **IF** you expect commits to be made on the topic branch concurrently with a 'main' branch, then the topic rebased off of the main branch, then commit dates/times will overlap. You can write a tool that will pull the git log (likely condensed in some form) and look at dates/times to determine if a rebase was used, as time will not increase linearly up the history.

Comment: @jsarbour I was trying to find something packaged in git, what happens in the log whe we use git rebase  ,   there is no trail ?

Comment: perhaps with `git hist`… (`git log --graph --decorate`)

Comment: Rebased compared to what? Looking at the log can tell you if rebase *should* be used, but it won't tell you if rebase *was* used, and frankly, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @chepner  what I am looking for is to know if a branch (topic) rebased another (main) . for me it matters. can be useful in some applacitions, we know that at the end the goal is to merge the codes is the goal, but sometimes knowing how it happened is practical.

Comment: Outside the reflog, that information simply doesn't exist. The rebase operation rewrites commit history; it isn't itself *part* of that history.

Answer (score 0):

The following command gives you the root commit of your feature branch

```
git merge-base the-branch develop
```

On the other hand you can check the number of commits between 2 revs by

```
git rev-list --left-right --count rev1...rev2
```

Anything greater then 0 means that there can be made rebase on feature branch

```
git rev-list --count develop...`(git merge-base the-branch develop)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I always do this with a simple visual check.

```
git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate
```

This will print out a very nice graphical view of the git log.  Then you can see if a branch is based off of `master` (or any other branch) by making sure that there is a direct line of `*`'s going back to `master`.

---

For example, in the graph below you can see that the `foo` branch (line 3) is based off of `master`, but the `bar` branch (line 1) is based off of commit `31aaea6`

```
* 820ee6d (bar) Second commit not off master
* 9dd860f First commit not off master
| * 58e01a5 (foo) Recreate quiz from code
| * 725aa0e Add grading capability to quiz
| *   835dbb9 (origin/master, master) Implement the blog
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 01c1d1a Add the date to the blog post cards
| * f96960d Implement blog code syntax highlighting
| * d88b941 Show featured photos on the home page
|/  
*   31aaea6 Add photoswipe image gallery
```

Answer (score 0):

Merging with `git merge --ff-only <topic-branch>` only succeeds if the target branch's `HEAD` is an ancestor of the `topic-branch`, i.e. that `topic-branch` has been rebased onto the target branch if the target branch was updated since `topic-branch` was branched off of it. Also see the [fast-forward merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast_forward_merge) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Git rebase is very important in a whole SDLC process since it maintains and keeps the commit history very clean. Though, BitBucket do not have this feature on it's GUI unlike it's alternatives. But here's a way to check if the branch is properly rebased on top of main-branch before merging it.

```
git fetch
git log --graph <branch-to-merge> <main-branch>
```

> The git fetch command downloads commits, files, and refs from a remote
> repository into your local repo and the second command gives a nice visual representation of the base of the branch-to-merge it's based off of. If it's a linear line/graph then the branch-to-merge is based off of the latest code/commit on the main-branch.